# list assignment index out of range using python 3.6, backpropagation

Tags: python

```
IndexError : list assignment index out of range
```

here is my code on training the dataset

```
def train_network (network, train,l_rate,n_epoch,n_outputs):
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
       sum_error = 0
       for row in train:
           outputs = forward_propagate(network,row)
           expected = [0 for in in range(n_outputs)]
           expected[row[-1]] = 1
```

I get the error on line `expected[row[-1]]=1` wat could be wrong

Comment: Please format your code using the code formatting style

Comment: Anything could be wrong. Does _each_ `row` have at least one item? Does _each_ `expected` have an item number `row[-1]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
expected = [0 for in in range(n_outputs)]
expected[row[-1]] = 1
```

Since no numbers are provided, for all we know `n_outputs` can be some very small number that does not support what `row[-1]` contains.
Example:

```
expected = [0 for i in range(100)] #n_outputs = 100
expected[999] = 1 #row[-1] = 999
#This will hit your error because expected[999] does not exist.
```